# Can I compile .NET C# code on my Mac?

Tags: windows, development, microsoft

I need a way to cross compile a short piece of .NET C# code to a dll, which will then run a client's Windows environment.

I run OS X 10.9.2 on an iMac.

Does anyone know what tools allow this?

I would rather not install Parallels and Windows if I can find a way to cross compile this without needing that heavy of an installation of Microsoft tools.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check out the Mono Project. It may be what you are looking for.

[http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aOSX)

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) is a cross-platform IDE primarily designed for C# and other .NET languages. MonoDevelop enables developers to quickly write desktop and ASP.NET Web applications on Linux, Windows and Mac OSX. MonoDevelop makes it easy for developers to port .NET applications created with Visual Studio to Linux and Mac OSX maintaining a single code base for all platforms.

Comment: http://monodevelop.com/ 

MonoDevelop is a cross-platform IDE primarily designed for C# and other .NET languages. MonoDevelop enables developers to quickly write desktop and ASP.NET Web applications on Linux, Windows and Mac OSX. MonoDevelop makes it easy for developers to port .NET applications created with Visual Studio to Linux and Mac OSX maintaining a single code base for all platforms.

--

If you can't compile your code correctly with MonoDevelop, they you may have no choice but to run a VM.

Comment: Thx, I've been looking at Mono, but while it should work, I've found no clear "how to" either install or use it.

Comment: @Jagra There are a few tutorial videos here: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=monodevelop+install+mac

Comment: MonoDevelop mimics Visual Studio, so it should be easy for you to use.

Comment: Just to iron out any doubt: **Yes**, if you compile a DLL on Mono, it will run on Windows without any modification whatsoever, *given that you don't use any specific Mono libraries*, such as Mono.Addin or Mono.Simd. It goes both ways, too - a DLL/EXE compiled on Visual Studio will run unmodifed on Mono, given that you don't use any specific Microsoft/Windows libraries such as WPF, Workflow Foundation, COM+ etc.

Comment: @Jagra: Once you install Mono (and MonoDevelop if you want it) from http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html, it's very easy to use. Even without MonoDevelop, you _should_ be able to compile most .sln projects straight from Visual Studio, using `xbuild`.

Comment: Can you use this alongside developers who are using Visual Studio?

Comment: `brew cask install dotnet-sdk`

will install both the **.NET runtimes** and the **sdk**

Answer (score 13):

You can install it with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install mono
```

Then you can use it with:

```
mcs hello.cs
mono hello.exe
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have a Mac you can compile C# like this:

Compile: `mcs fileName.cs`
Run: `mono fileName.exe`

If you don't have [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) installed on your Mac, you can google it and install it and then you will be good to go. You don't need Windows to do this.

Answer (score 2):

No personal experience with this IDE but this looks like it will work:
http://monodevelop.com

Answer (score 2):

You may now want to look into the following

Xamarin
https://www.xamarin.com/

Visual Studio for Mac
https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/

Answer (score 2):

> Can I compile .NET C# code on my Mac?

You can compile C# code yes.

> I would rather not install Parallels and Windows if I can find a way
>   to cross compile this without needing that heavy of an installation of
>   Microsoft tools.

**Mono [does not have 100% compatibility](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/) with the .NET implementation.**

The Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) is a framework for executing managed code.  The CLI consists of several parts including a Virtual Execution System (VES).  .NET's VES is the Common language Runtime.  Mono has it's own separate VES implementation.

In other words, at the very least do not expect to run code that has **only been tested in a *nix/OSX environment to run without testing it on a windows environment**.